# Questions about void pointers

Tags: c, syntax, void-pointers

I have two questions about void pointers; we have:

```
void * foo=malloc(99) 
void **bar=(void**)malloc(99);

int i=1;
bar++;
*bar = foo;
```

1.Is the above equivalent to the following?

```
bar[i++] = foo;
```

If yes it's unexpected because `bar++;` moves the double pointer forward and not single pointer, which is different from non void types.

2.Why is it fine to return `void**` from a `void * foo();`?

For example:

```
 void * foo(){
     void ** bar;
     return bar;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.Is the above equivalent to the following?
>
> ```
> bar[i++] = foo;
> ```
>
> If yes it's unexpected because bar++; moves the double
>   pointer forward and not single pointer, which is different from non
>   void types.

It's fine because `bar` is a pointer to an array of pointers. The size of a `void*` is known (it's the size of a pointer), so you know where the next element of a `void**` array is.

> 2.Why is it fine to return `void**` from a `void * foo();`?

Because `void*` is a pointer to anything. A pointer to a pointer to anything is a pointer to anything, so `void**` can be implicitly converted to `void*`.

Comment: But `bar[i++]` advances a `void*` type and `bar++;` advances a `void**` type.

Comment: @kuhaku No they don't. `bar[i++]` accesses `bar` (a `void**`) at the `i`th position, and increments `i`. `bar++` advances `bar` by one element.

Comment: "A pointer to a pointer to anything is a pointer to anything" -- it would be better to say that it's a pointer to *something* (only `void*` is a pointer to *anything*).